# Auto run a subroutine every 5 minutes after I start it by clicking a button on UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have subroutine, which is part of a bigger program. It is activated by the click of a button, which I click at 9.10am. After that, it needs to run every 5 minutes. Steps in the subroutine are:

- Fetch data in 2 power queries
- Paste certain data on labels in an user form
- Copy data from one sheet to another
- Save a chart in a folder where the sheet is saved
- Take the chart and show it on user form

All this is done with the UserForm open and the actual Excel sheet hidden. All these steps work when I manually click on the button to run the code but I have not been able to get it automated.

I have tried `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")` but it works randomly. Not every five minutes.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton12_Click()

    Dim FName As String
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    'Refresh Queries
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    'Update userForm
    Trade.Label155.Caption = Sheets("Dump").Range("C16")
    Trade.Label156.Caption = Sheets("Dump").Range("C20")
    Trade.Label158.Caption = Sheets("Dump").Range("C18")
    Trade.Label159.Caption = Sheets("Dump").Range("C22")
    Trade.Label161.Caption = Sheets("Dump").Range("C17")
    Trade.Label162.Caption = Sheets("Dump").Range("C21")
    Trade.Label164.Caption = Format(Sheets("Dump").Range("C19"), "#.00")
    Trade.Label165.Caption = Format(Sheets("Dump").Range("C23"), "#.00")
    Trade.Label166.Caption = Format(Sheets("Dump").Range("C37"), "hh:mm")
    'Data for Chart
    Sheets("OI Data").Select
    Range("G31:K31").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dump").Select
    Range("DI1048576").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    'Paste Chart in UserForm
    Call NiftyChart
    FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.gif"
    Me.Image3.Picture = LoadPicture(FName)
    
    'Data for Chart
    Sheets("OI Data").Select
    Range("AF31:AJ31").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Dump").Select
    Range("DQ1048576").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Paste Chart in UserForm
    Call BankNiftyChart
    FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp2.gif"
    Me.Image4.Picture = LoadPicture(FName)
    
    MultiPage1.Height = 550
    Trade.Height = 650
End Sub

Private Sub NiftyChart()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim FName As String
    
    Set MyChart = Sheets("OI Charts").ChartObjects(1).Chart
    FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.gif"
    MyChart.Export Filename:=FName, FilterName:="GIF"
    End Sub

    Private Sub BankNiftyChart()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim FName As String
    
    Set MyChart = Sheets("OI Charts").ChartObjects(2).Chart
    FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp2.gif"
    MyChart.Export Filename:=FName, FilterName:="GIF"
End Sub
```

Comment: If you're having problems with your code then it's useful to post the whole (relevant) code.   `OnTime` is the way to do this, but you need to set it up correctly otherwise you can end up with concurrent scheduled runs.

Comment: Apologies Tim, I am new to this. Here is code below.

Comment: You can edit your question and add the code there   https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76969781/edit

Comment: Code updated Tim.

Comment: I could not update a screenshot of the UserForm

Comment: `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")` where is the method name to be run?

Comment: Initially I had added this entire code in a module and called it with Application.Ontime from the button of UserForm. However that did not work.

Comment: Is it possible to get on a ZOOM call? I can share my desktop and show you the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general pattern for using `OnTime`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim nextRun  'stores the next run time

Sub RunTimer()
    
    MyProc  'call the procedure
    'schedule the next run for 5 min after the procedure is done
    nextRun = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")     'save next run time in global varaible
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=nextRun, _
                       Procedure:="RunTimer", schedule:=True
End Sub

'cancel any scheduled run
Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=nextRun, _
                       Procedure:="RunTimer", schedule:=False
End Sub

'This is the procedure you want to run on a timer...
Sub MyProc()
    Debug.Print Now, "Ran MyProc"
End Sub
```

Note this will schedule for 5min after `MyProc` is complete.  You *could* set the next schedule *before* calling `MyProc`, if you're sure there will be no delays in its run.

Comment: So, I can move my code to a module, add this code to be executed at CommandButton12_Click and then it will run my code every five minutes till there is a error or till I close the workbook. 
Is my assumption correct?

Comment: That should work, yes.