# How to auto save only if worksheet is open?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet programmed to auto save every 30 minutes. But when I close it and there are other spreadsheets open, every 30 minutes it opens again to save. I've tried turning off the timer when closing this spreadsheet but it doesn't work. Is there a solution?

Code to save:

```
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), Procedure:="autoSalvar", Schedule:=True
```

Code I tried to turn off the timer before closing:

```
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), Procedure:="autoSalvar", Schedule:=False
```

Comment: Does `autoSalvar` open the workbook to save it?

Comment: When cancelling the OnTime you need to use the *exact same time* you used to schedule the run.  Typically you'd save that in a global variable when you set up each run.  See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76973561/478884

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop it in that way. It must refer to the **absolute time when it should start again**. Please, try the next way:

1. Place the two variables on to of the standard module where `autoSalvar` exists (in the declarations area):

```
Public macroName As String
Public timeToFire As Date
```

2. Place the next subs, to be called by `autoSalvar`, respectively, `BeforeClose` event:

```
Sub startOnTime()
    timeToFire = Now + TimeValue("00:30:00")
    sMacro = "autoSalvar"
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=timeToFire , Procedure:=macroName, Schedule:=True
End Sub
```

```
Sub StopOnTime()
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=timeToFire , Procedure:=macroName, Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

You must use `OnTime` calling `startOnTime` and stop it calling `StopOnTime`...

Comment: I put the "startOnTime" event for when the spreadsheet is opened and the "StopOnTime" event for when the spreadsheet is closed. Error 1004 is returned when opening the worksheet. Why would it be?

Comment: @Júlio César Pedrini You must put the `startOnTime` exactly instead of `Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), Procedure:="autoSalvar", Schedule:=True`. In the place **where this code exists**. Inside `autoSalvar`, too, if it exists there! And `StopOnTime` in the `Before_Close` event code, instead of `Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now + TimeValue("00:30:00"), Procedure:="autoSalvar", Schedule:=False`. But **did you declare the first two variable (item 1. in the answer) on top of a standard module**? You probably, did  not... Am I wrong?

Comment: @Júlio César Pedrini  Didn't you make it working?

Comment: @Júlio César Pedrini Is it so complicated to send some feedback on a problem which you  raised and I only tried helping?